# (SU) Windows Command line to save network log of Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, logging

I can view the Network log of a website manually but I was wondering if there is a way to use the Windows command line to open the site and then save the network log information out to a log or text file?

I found this on another site but it didn't create the log;

```
Chrome.exe--log-net-log=C:\Temp\some_file_name.json
```

Do I have to enable developer mode in anyway first ? If so, how do I do that ?

Comment: `Chrome.exe--log-net-log` should have a space after `exe`

Comment: Thank you, I missed that :) Is there anyway to filter what I want to keep? When I type in url into the filter box it gets ride of almost everything so I would like it to filter what I want to Keep in the log instead of remove.

Comment: No idea. But I would create a complete log and filter post logging ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I found this on another site but it didn't create the log;

> ```
> Chrome.exe--log-net-log=C:\Temp\some_file_name.json
> ```

You are missing a space after `Chrome.exe`.

Try the following

```
Chrome.exe --log-net-log=C:\Temp\some_file_name.json
          ^
```